# K-means clustering assumptions?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

iam new to machine learning in this case k-means clustering. i have learn how k-means clustering works but i look this website about k-means assumptions http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_assumptions.html and iam still confuse what is exactly means? can anyone explain whats is the k-means assumption purpose in that website? (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It illustrates how K-means performs on different datasets that have a different underlying structure. If you are suspecting that your own dataset might have one of those structures then this example helps you decide whether to use K-means clustering or not.